# Can't find System.Web v2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio 2015. I created a .net 3.5 web application. However, when I go to debug it says it can't find System.Web. I have .net 3.5 installed on my machine. What could I possibly be missing?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Show all your using statements as it appears in your code, and double check there is an assembly reference in your web.config that matches version 3.5.

Comment: That's what I did as well...

Comment: I think my comment was removed, after changing the target framework to 4.0 I no longer had any issues. I also removed any references to a script manager in my master page.